# How to check if that data already exist in the database before save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hey guys I have a question, how to do validations before saving the edited or posted (post or put action ) data in mongoose !?

for Example, if action already exist in the database, the user will receive a some sort of error. I try this but not working :
1-NOT WORK

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var actionSchema = new Schema({
    action: {
          type: String,
          required: true,

            },
    });

var data = mongoose.model('Action', actionSchema);

actionSchema.pre('save', function (next) { // Middlware to verify if action already existe
   var self = this;
   data.find({
     action: self.action
   }, function (err, actions) {
     if (!actions.length) {
         next();
      } else {
          console.log('action exists: ', self.name);
          next(new Error("Action exists!"));
      }
   });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Action', actionSchema);
```

2 --- NOT WORK SECOND METHODE : ------------------------------------

```
 var data = mongoose.model('Action', actionSchema);

actionSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
data.count({
    action: this.action
}, function (err, count) {
    if (count == 1) {
        console.log('action exists: ', this.action);
        next(new Error("Action exists!"));
        //already exists
      } else {
          next();
          //do the action 
      }
   });
  });
```

3- WORKING ALTERNATIVE -- NODE JS CONTROLLER ----I found this trick (work good) that is to do a check before the update (check) 
But I would like to know if there is possibility to do it before my save in my model MONGOOSE !?

```
 // router.put('/actions/:action_id');

 Action.findById(req.params.action_id, function (err, upaction) {
   if (err) { //no action id in database match with params.action_id
       res.send(err);
   } else { // find == true 


 // chek if action name existe
    Action.findOne({ 
                    'action': req.body.action
                })
          .exec(function (err, found_action) {
                    if (err) { // ereur bizare sest produite
                        next(err);
                    }

                      if (found_action) { // name action exist
                         res.send('name action existe');
                      } 
          else { // name action no exist

          upaction.action = req.body.action;

                        upaction.save(function (err, acti) {
                            if (err) {
                                res.send('error on save');
                            }
                            res.send(upaction); // send a document
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: i dont understand why u doing so many operations to do a single operation .if u want to unique value in your action field than you can use   "action: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          unique:true
            },"
than you cant add or update already exist value in action field than mongoose throw error automatically.

Comment: I used this but with each POST the document is added.
Ex: action 1: "stack"
Action 2 "stack"
....

Comment: I have not used all these operations at the same time.

Comment: it is a little bit late but are you building an api.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the data already avaliable and then perform the action you want

```
 var data = mongoose.model('data', actionSchema);
 data.count({action: this.action}, function(err, count) {
   if(count == 1){
     //already exists
    }
      else{
   actionSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
       });
         }
      });
```

Comment: TypeError: actionSchema.count is not a function

Comment: console.log(count) inside the function and see what returning

Comment: i think it's impossible to check if data already exist in Pre (Mongoose)

Comment: i will use this function in my controller NODE Js !?

Comment: you should count before Pre

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you doing too many operation to do a single operation. Mongodb provides update function which has ability to check and insert. If you want a document to be inserted only when some condition comes true or false. `update` can do that in a singly query. Here you go.

```
Action.update({ action:{ $eq:req.body.action }},{ $setOnInsert: new_action }, { upsert: true }, function(err, res){
    if(!err && !!res.upserted){
        // no document was found hence inserted
    }else if(!err && !res.upserted){
        // already existing
    }else{
        //  something wicked happend
    }
})
```

Here you need to pay attention that `new_action` must not be a instance of your mongoose model rather it should be simple object/document which you want to insert.

Comment: i use mongoose !

Comment: sorry!, actually I wrote mongodb syntax, I've updated it. Have a look.

Comment: Please see my answer !

Comment: I try your methode but not works ! the only methode work i have posted it ( see my post )

Comment: I examined my query and found there should be `$eq` at `$ne` in the update query. Kindly check the updated query and let me know if this solves your problem.